# retrieve dynamically created layout ID and match it to a list entry

Tags: java, android, android-layout

i have a list of objects (`l`) with data retrieved from a database. dynamically i create a table layout with this data and add a id for the table cell

```
row.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
    TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    row.setId(View.generateViewId());

rb.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
rb.setId(View.generateViewId());
rb.setText(l.getText());
rb.setOnClickListener(handleOnClickText(rb));
```

and this is the method that i'm interested on how to handle stuff

```
View.OnClickListener handleOnClickText(final TextView text) {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO
            // retrieve id of clicked item
            // match id to list entry
            // do something with it
        }
    };
}
```

my problem is how do i match the `id` of the clicked item (and how do i retrieve it) to the list entry that created it so that i can create queries for the database?

i have multiple elements in the table that are created by one list entry (a few TextView and a Button, but the issue is the same for all).

is it possible?

another solution i have in  mind is to create a mapping (dictionary?) of `id`'s to a list entry (how do i retrieve the `id` after `setId( )` to add it as a value?), but how do i retrieve the id is still a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,you could use map(dictionary).
Firstly:

```
public final static Map<String, Integer> ID_MAP = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

then:

```
int id = View.generateViewId();
ID_MAP.put("key_1", id);
rb.setId(id);
```

and use map key to get specific id like this:

```
int id = ID_MAP.get("key_1"); 
//do other things
```

Comment: great, just what i needed! but the question remains, how do i retrieve the `id` of the clicked item in the handler? i need to retrieve the string form the map based on the `id` of the clicked item

Comment: if(v.getId() == someid) {  } or use switch/case

Comment: ty! v.getId() is what i need i guess.